# How to determine which element has triggered event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a color picker as a learning project in JS. I wanted the `#screen` to show whatever color is pressed on it. How can i determine which element has been clicked and send its color value to the function so that `screen.style.backgroundColor: object.style.backgroundColor;`.

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var col1 = document.getElementById("color1");
var col2 = document.getElementById("color2");
var col3 = document.getElementById("color3");
var col4 = document.getElementById("color4");
var col5 = document.getElementById("color5");
var col6 = document.getElementById("color6");
var col7 = document.getElementById("color7");
var col8 = document.getElementById("color8");
var col9 = document.getElementById("color9");
var colors = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9];
var project = function(e) {
 console.log(e.srcElement.id.style.backgroundColor);
 var x = document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id);
 screen.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor;
}
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
 colors[i].addEventListener("click", project);
}
```

```css
#container, #screen {
    width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.color {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 float: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#color1 {
 background-color: red;
}
#color2 {
 background-color: green;
}
#color3 {
 background-color: blue;
}
#color4 {
 background-color: yellow;
}
#color5 {
 background-color: fuchsia;
}
#color6 {
 background-color: aqua;
}
#color7 {
 background-color: orange;
}
#color8 {
 background-color: khaki;
}
#color9 {
 background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div class="color" id="color1"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color2"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color3"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color4"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color5"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color6"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color7"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color8"></div>
      <div class="color" id="color9"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="screen"></div>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: you have set background color of each element by inline to get by pure JS or use jQuery

Comment: Are you using jquery in your application?

Comment: No I am a beginner, dont know jQuery.....anyway, i  tried experimenting and edited the JS part. Seems like it should have worked but it doesnt, can u take a look?

Comment: I can help you if you are using jQuery

Comment: Check my answer with the working snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using classes to set the background color you might have to set the className instead of the backgroundColor and move all the colors into css classes.

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var col1 = document.getElementById("color1");
var col2 = document.getElementById("color2");
var col3 = document.getElementById("color3");
var col4 = document.getElementById("color4");
var col5 = document.getElementById("color5");
var col6 = document.getElementById("color6");
var col7 = document.getElementById("color7");
var col8 = document.getElementById("color8");
var col9 = document.getElementById("color9");
var colors = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9];
for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    colors[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        screen.className = e.target.className;
    });
}
```

```css
#container, #screen {
    width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.color {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 float: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.color1 {
 background-color: red;
}
.color2 {
 background-color: green;
}
.color3 {
 background-color: blue;
}
.color4 {
 background-color: yellow;
}
.color5 {
 background-color: fuchsia;
}
.color6 {
 background-color: aqua;
}
.color7 {
 background-color: orange;
}
.color8 {
 background-color: khaki;
}
.color9 {
 background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
 <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div class="color color1" id="color1"></div>
      <div class="color color2" id="color2"></div>
      <div class="color color3" id="color3"></div>
      <div class="color color4" id="color4"></div>
      <div class="color color5" id="color5"></div>
      <div class="color color6" id="color6"></div>
      <div class="color color7" id="color7"></div>
      <div class="color color8" id="color8"></div>
      <div class="color color9" id="color9"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="screen"></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method.

First, add a function that will get the computed style from css sheet:

```
function test(event) {
  var target = event.target?event.target:event.srcElement;

  var style = window.getComputedStyle(target);
  alert(style.getPropertyValue("background-color"));
}
```

Then, add an event listener to every element with "color" class:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var colors = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
  for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) 
    colors[i].addEventListener('click', test,false);
}
```

It will alert your color in rgb(), at least in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the clicked element from the passed event object:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    colors[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        alert(event.target.style.backgroundColor);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I made this fiddle for you. Since you are using css to define your background you should recognize your color by the ID of the object.

This is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6rq79taa/

So this is the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="load()">
<div id="container">
            <div class="color" id="color1"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color2"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color3"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color4"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color5"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color6"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color7"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color8"></div>
            <div class="color" id="color9"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="screen"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function load() {
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var col1 = document.getElementById("color1");
var col2 = document.getElementById("color2");
var col3 = document.getElementById("color3");
var col4 = document.getElementById("color4");
var col5 = document.getElementById("color5");
var col6 = document.getElementById("color6");
var col7 = document.getElementById("color7");
var col8 = document.getElementById("color8");
var col9 = document.getElementById("color9");
var colors = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9];

for(var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].addEventListener("click", colorName);
}
};

function colorName(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.id);
};
```

**CSS**

```
.color {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#color1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#color2 {
    background-color: green;
}
#color3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#color4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#color5 {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
#color6 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
#color7 {
    background-color: orange;
}
#color8 {
    background-color: khaki;
}
#color9 {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changecolor(colorname){
 document.getElementById("screen").style.backgroundColor = colorname;
 }
```

```css
#container, #screen {
    width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.color {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 float: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#color1 {
 background-color: red;
}
#color2 {
 background-color: green;
}
#color3 {
 background-color: blue;
}
#color4 {
 background-color: yellow;
}
#color5 {
 background-color: fuchsia;
}
#color6 {
 background-color: aqua;
}
#color7 {
 background-color: orange;
}
#color8 {
 background-color: khaki;
}
#color9 {
 background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container">
                <div  class="color" id="color1" onclick='changecolor("red")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color2" onclick='changecolor("green")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color3" onclick='changecolor("blue")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color4" onclick='changecolor("yellow")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color5" onclick='changecolor("fuchsia")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color6" onclick='changecolor("aqua")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color7" onclick='changecolor("orange")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                <div  class="color" id="color8" onclick='changecolor("khaki")'><a href="#"></a></div>
                    <div  class="color" id="color9" onclick='changecolor("silver")'><a href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="screen"></div><br/>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on "Marcin O" answer

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("color" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(this);
    screen.style.backgroundColor = style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
  });
}
```

```css
#container,
#screen {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.color {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#color1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#color2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#color3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#color4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#color5 {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
#color6 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
#color7 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#color8 {
  background-color: khaki;
}
#color9 {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="color" id="color1"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color2"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color3"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color4"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color5"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color6"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color7"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color8"></div>
    <div class="color" id="color9"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="screen"></div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```